# Steffensen's method in MATLAB with out using the Aitken's process

Tags: matlab

I have implemented the following code of the Steffensen's method but with out using the implementation of the Aitken's delta-squared process:

```
%Test of Steffesen's Method

function st(x0)

    tol=10^-6; % tolerance
    itmax=1000; % max number of iterations
    itnum=0; % iterations counter


    disp([itnum,x0])
    x1=(f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0))/f1(x0);
    itnum=itnum+1;
    disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])

    while abs((x0-x1)/x0)>tol && itnum<itmax
        x0=x1;
        x1=(f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0))/f1(x0);
        itnum=itnum+1;
        disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])
    end

end


function y=f1(x)
y=x^3+x-3;
end
function y=f2(x)
    y=x-tan(x);
end
```

The thing is that when I want to tested with `f1` and `x0=1` this doesn't converge and the same problem when I run it with `x0=2`, and I know that the root is in   1.302775637720899. Can someone help me to fix this mistake please?

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan for the improvement ;)

Comment: The solution seems to grow out of bounds for every number you input. I suspect it has to do with the `y = x^3 + x - 3` which will always grow as soon as `x>1`

Comment: But then my code works fine isn't? or what is my mistake ? Thanks

Comment: It runs without errors at least, but never converges as far as I can see. I do not know the Steffensen's method, so I do not know whether you made a mistake in that.

Comment: Well you can take a look over here please  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method  :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know what root you gave there, but it's not the root for the polynomial in `f1`. Using MATLAB's `roots` command on that polynomial gives:

```
roots([1, 0, 1, -3])

ans =

  -0.6067 + 1.4506i
  -0.6067 - 1.4506i
   1.2134 + 0.0000i
```

showing one real root at 1.2134. That being said, your issue is not with your code per se, but that you implemented the algorithm incorrectly. Wikipedia states:

[image: alg1]

where g(xn) is

[image: alg2]

Combining those two does not give what you have above, it gives :

`x1=x0 -f1(x0)^2/(f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0));`

That should produce the correct result. Also, it will not work for your second function, f2, since it is singular at the root.

Comment: Ok, let me try that If I have problems can I let you know ?

Comment: And I have plot that in wolfram alpha and my root seems correct :) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Bx-3